# What is the best practice of getting element’s height in controller

Tags: ember.js

In this case, there is a element which is position:fixed and its top(css) depends on another element's height, 
what is the best practice of getting that element's height in controller?

Or how can we do it dynamically?

Comment: Extract it into a component and deal with the size in [didReceiveAttrs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_formatting-component-attributes-with-code-didreceiveattrs-code)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the height() function from a JavaScript. If you know the ID of that element for example you have a `<div id="something"></div>` then in the controller say `var height = Ember.$("#something").height();`.

Thats all what you need to do.

Comment: It's from the jQuery

Comment: @kristjanreinhold
here is my code.
init(){
  var height = Ember.$("title-bar").height();}

Comment: Youre missing "#" - id selector or "." for class